# Excel duplicate words in row

Tags: excel

How do I count only as "2" if the word "apple" show in the same row like row3 and row4 ? The code i need is in Microsoft excel 2010 not vba

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: ever tried google?

Comment: 10 seconds of search: https://exceljet.net/formula/count-cells-that-contain-specific-text

Comment: @Kathara I don't think your link answers the question. They're looking for the number of rows that contain the value. Not the count of values

Comment: @Tom yes it does... it's the function that you need: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34 you'll just have to adapt it to your needs... otherwise your question is unclear...

Comment: @Kathara `COUNTIF` will not consider row values and will return 8 rather than 2.

Answer (score 0):

Got very close to figuring out a formula but I'm afraid I bailed and created a UDF instead after getting fed up.

Paste the following into a module in the vba editor (will have to save the file as a `.xlsm` now as well). This will work for all 2D ranges (i.e. where the count of rows and the count of columns are both greater than 1) a 1D range you can use `COUNTIF` as stated in the comments above.

```
Public Function CountStringOccurence(count_text As String, within_range As Range) As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    ' Create array of 1's and 0's (Numerical trues and falses)
    arr = Application.Evaluate("--(" & within_range.Parent.Name & "!" & within_range.Address & "=""" & count_text & """)")
    ' Loop through each row array
    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        ' Get max value in each row and sum (i.e. if there is a True present add it to the total count)
        CountStringOccurence = CountStringOccurence + Application.Max(Application.Index(arr, i, 0))
    Next i
End Function
```

and call it using `CountStringOccurence(B7,A3:G4)`

In the function it first populates an array from the range with 1 if the value in the range matches the string wanted and 0 if it doesn't. It then loops through each row in the array summing the maximum value in the row (i.e. 1 if the value exists and 0 if it doesn't). It then feeds the answer back to the Excel cell

If someone can come up with a formula for it though I'd love to see it.

If you can add an extra column to sheet you can also achieve this doing:
Last column in sheet enter `=MAX(--(A3:G3=$B$7))` for each row and then sum this column to get your answer

Comment: Still don't understand what you're trying to achieve... do you want to check whether a string is appearing more than once in a row? Do you want to check whether it exists in one row and another? Try to explain it clearer...

Comment: I inferred the OP's question as wanting to count the number of rows that contain a specific value. In their example both rows contain the value "apple" so the answer is `2` which is what the above generates (except for a 1D range where it will fall over but for that you could use a `COUNTIF`)

Comment: aaaah much clearer now. This can be done with a formula... I'll report back when finding it ;)

Comment: Cheers - I'm sure it can be I just couldn't figure it out myself. Will be interested to see what you come up with

Comment: is there a possibility to add another column to the sheet?

Comment: Wasn't sure. you could do it easily if that's the case but I was trying to do it all in one formula

Comment: Problem in doing it in one formula is, that you'll have to add the ranges for each row... I'll provide you the code in vba

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most simple way to do it but here you go:

```
Public Sub getRowCountOfStringOccurance()

    Dim thisRange As Range
    Set thisRange = Selection

    MsgBox (countStringOccurancesInRows("apple", thisRange))


End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function countStringOccurancesInRows(stringToFind As String, searchRange As Range) As Integer

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    Dim firstRow As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Dim firstColumn As Integer
    Dim lastColumn As Integer

    Dim rowOccurances As Integer
    rowOccurances = 0

    Dim occurances As Integer
    occurances = 0

    firstRow = searchRange.Rows(1).Row
    lastRow = searchRange.Rows.Count + firstRow - 1

    firstColumn = searchRange.Columns(1).Column
    lastColumn = searchRange.Columns.Count + firstColumn - 1

    For thisRow = firstRow To lastRow
        For thisColumn = firstColumn To lastColumn
            If (ws.Cells(thisRow, thisColumn) = stringToFind) Then
                rowOccurances = rowOccurances + 1
            End If
        Next
        If (rowOccurances > 0) Then
            occurances = occurances + 1
        End If
    Next

    countStringOccurancesInRows = occurances

End Function
```

Be aware that I've entered the string for the moment and the range to be searched through has to be selected in the sheet. It will then give a messagebox with the result. While testing I had no issues.

Comment: This is a very long way to do the same thing in my vba. And far more iterative. Please have a look at my code. If you don't understand it I can explain further

Comment: Hope you don't mind - [I've just done a code review for you](https://anotepad.com/notes/xtgsn6)